# reloadRows doesn't work properly

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4

As the text extends 100 characters, a more button appears in my `commentCell`. When I press on it, the cell should limit the lines to 0 and reload the cell.

The problem is that I have to press the cell twice to enlarge and twice to minimize the cell.

This is my code for enlarging the cell:

```
@IBAction func expandTextField(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let currentIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    self.state = !self.state
    print(state)

    self.tapMore.setTitle(self.state ? self.decreaseState: self.expandState, for: .normal)
    self.commentLabel.numberOfLines = (self.state ? self.expandedLines: self.numberOfLines)

    self.parentViewControllerCommentCell?.tableView.reloadRows(at: [currentIndexPath], with: .none)
}
```

**Note:** The function works fine but only if clicked a total of 2 times. The correct cell enlarges, the description of the button changes accordingly.

**Important**

I tried with print statements to see when the state changes. As I said it only does it every second time.

```
true
true
false 
false
```

When I delete the

```
self.parentViewControllerCommentCell?.tableView.reloadRows(at: [currentIndexPath], with: .none)
```

function, it changes within just one click.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` **reuses cells**. When you reload a row, it gets replaced with a cell that is available for reusement.

It is **not guaranteed** that the reused cell will have the parameters you set up in the cell being replaced.

You should store whether the character count in the table view has reached 100 in a boolean in your **data store** and  not the cell itself.